# Is the Tuple in MDX an implicit crossjoin?

Tags: mdx

Are the two statements equivalent?

Tuple:

```
  SELECT  {[Measures].[Volume]}  ON COLUMNS, 
  ([Product].[Product Id].[Product Id].AllMembers
  ,[Time].[Time].[Year].AllMembers)  ON ROWS 
   FROM [My Cube]
```

Versus explicit crossjoin:

```
SELECT  {[Measures].[Volume]}  ON COLUMNS, 
  [Product].[Product Id].[Product Id].AllMembers
       * [Time].[Time].[Year].AllMembers  ON ROWS 
       FROM [My Cube]
```

They seem to return the same result, but it seemed from the reading I have done that they shouldn't (at least not always).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have in your first query is not a tuple. Tuples are made up of a collection of one or more members

eg. (*member1, member2, ...*)

Where as what you have is (*set1, set2 ...*). which I think of as a subcube as this is what is use when defining subcubes for scope statements. And a subcube is essentially an implied crossjoin, so your two queries should return the same result.